# Sharepoint Calendar view, check if event is recurring

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Calendar in my SharePoint online Project. It has both recurring and none recurring events.

[image]

Is there some way that I can make a `Column` or something, where I can see if it's, is or not a recurring event?

The reason why I need this is that I'm displaying an amount the events in a Template on my page. But I would get a property like `Location` that contains the information about if the event is or not recurring.

Answer (score 1):

The  column to the left of the Title column is the recurrence indicator column. Please find the difference below :

[image]

**UPDATED as per comment :**

Client Side Rendering is usually the adopted method to achieve this kind of requirement, however CSR does not work with Calendars. So I have created a JSOM implementation that gets your requriement done.

Since you want the recurrence value to be shown in another column, the below JSOM script that will read the **Recurrence** column in the calendar(internalName : **fRecurrence**) and updates the **Title** column with corresponding value(whether recurring or not).

*Use the below code after proper code clean up as it was tested only for functionality implementation and not production ready.*

[image]

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(queryListItems, "sp.js");

});
var oWebsite ;

var context; 
function queryListItems() {  
     context = new SP.ClientContext();  

     var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestCalendar');           
     var caml = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();    

     returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);  
     context.load(returnedItems);            
     context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);  
  }    

  function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) {  

     var itemArray = [];
     var i =0;
     var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();  

     while (enumerator.moveNext()) {         
     var listItem = enumerator.get_current();  

     //Remove this alert after testing
     alert('Recurrence: ' + listItem.get_item('fRecurrence') );       

     itemArray[i] = listItem; 
     var value = listItem.get_item('fRecurrence');
     if(value != true)         {
       listItem.set_item('Title', 'Not Recurring!');  
       listItem.update();
     } 
     else{
     listItem.set_item('Title', 'Recurring!');  
       listItem.update();
    }
      context.load(itemArray[i++]);

  }  
    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
 }  

 function onFailedCallback(sender, args) {  
  alert('Message: ' + args.get_message()); 
}  
function onQuerySucceeded() {
  alert('Items Updated');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
 </script>
```

**Note :** The JSOM code will run on every page load and populate the title column. You will have to check for any other race condition dependencies yourself.

Comment: Yes I know it's a Recurring event indicator, but it's not accessible as a Column,

Comment: I've clearly said i need a it to be a column